# kendo ui getting started w/ angular error Uncaught TypeError

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui

I'm getting started with kendo & angular - free version - and I have a page that renders and behaves okay, but throws an error in the background.

I get an
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'jQuery' of undefined" in /js/kendo.angular.min.js:16

I think I have a wrong dependency / am missing one, but I'm not sure which. The kendo scripts and css are from the core download page http://www.telerik.com/download/kendo-ui-core

Whats going on here?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Kendo With Angular</title>
<link href="kendo/styles/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="kendo/styles/kendo.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="kendo/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="kendo/js/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="kendo/js/kendo.angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="kendo/js/kendo.ui.core.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body ng-app="KendoDemo">

<div ng-controller="Demo">
    {{hello}}

    <input kendo-date-picker k-ng-model="dateObject" />

    {{date | date:'fullDate'}}

    {{dateObject | date:'fullDate'}}
</div>
<script>

    angular.module('KendoDemo',['kendo.directives'])
           .controller('Demo', function($scope) {

        $scope.hello = 'Hello World';
    })

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The kendo.ui.core.js script needs to go before the kendo.angular.js script:

proper script order

```
<script src="kendo/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="kendo/js/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="kendo/js/kendo.ui.core.min.js"></script>
<script src="kendo/js/kendo.angular.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Your explanation does not match your answer. There are two files containing the word "angular".

Comment: He means kendo.ui.core.min.js should preceed kendo.angular.min.js

Comment: This helped when nothing else would. Thanks :)